# Can we have both 32 bit & 64 bit architecture on a single machine

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

Most softwares support 32 bit architecture. Some high end software need 64 bit architecture. Can we have both architecture on a single distro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Ubuntu has what it calls multi-arch support in it's 64 bit versions.

All it means is that the 32 bit and 64 bit libraries exist on the same system in different directories.  The software knows how to locate and load the correct version.

By default, the 32 bit libraries may not be installed but you're able to do so using apt.

"Some high end software?"  Do you release that most software is 64 bit now.  The 64 bit architecture has been around for quite some time now and is not limited to what you might be calling "high end software".  Even bash is 64 bit.

Comment: I have installed 32 bit distro. But my software need 64 bit configuration. Can i upgrade to a 64 bit configuration with some terminal commands

Comment: It is possible only if you upgrade your kernel to a 64bit kernel and install all the 64bit libraries across.  Pretty much no.  You should have installed the 64bit version.  I'm assuming you have 64bit CPU ?  If not, you're not going to be able to.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/111975/can-i-run-64-bit-executables-on-a-32-bit-linux

Comment: Architecture: i686
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit 
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core: 1 
Core(s) per socket: 2 
Socket(s): 1 
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel 
CPU family: 6 
Model: 23 
Stepping: 10 
CPU MHz: 2800.000 
BogoMIPS: 5586.12 
Virtualization: VT-x 
L1d cache: 32K 
L1i cache: 32K 
L2 cache: 2048K

Comment: Suggest you reinstall a 64-bit version.  There are very few apps that need 32bit.